# What is meant by shift in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, quandl

I am stuck in the following lines

```
import quandl,math
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from  sklearn import preprocessing ,cross_validation , svm
from sklearn.linear_model import  LinearRegression


df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')




df = df[['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close','Adj. Volume']]

df['HL_PCT'] = (df["Adj. High"] - df['Adj. Close'])/df['Adj. Close'] * 100
df['PCT_CHANGE'] = (df["Adj. Close"] - df['Adj. Open'])/df['Adj. Open'] * 100

df = df[['Adj. Close','HL_PCT','PCT_CHANGE','Adj. Open']]

forecast_col = 'Adj. Close'

df.fillna(-99999,inplace = True)

forecast_out = int(math.ceil(.1*len(df)))

df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)
print df.head()
```

I couldn't understand what is meant by df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)

Please explain the command and what is does??

Comment: When forecasting, you're "lagging" the column, so the negative shift is shifting the column forward by the value of forecast_out.

Comment: did you read the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift)?

Comment: @TTT like overlaying the curve snapshot starting from the current timestamp to the old snapshot, to see the curve tendency?

Answer (score 22):

Shift function of pandas.Dataframe shifts index by desired number of periods with an optional time freq. For further information on shift function please refer this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html).

Here is the small example of column values being shifted:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2000-01-03", "2000-01-03", "2000-03-05", "2000-01-03", "2000-03-05",
                        "2000-03-05", "2000-07-03", "2000-01-03", "2000-07-03", "2000-07-03"],
               "variable": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D"],
               "no": [1, 2.2, 3.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.1, 2, 3],
               "value": [0.469112, -0.282863, -1.509059, -1.135632, 1.212112, -0.173215,
                         0.119209, -1.044236, -0.861849, None]})
```

Below is the column value before it is shifted

```
df['value']
```

output

```
0    0.469112
1   -0.282863
2   -1.509059
3   -1.135632
4    1.212112
5   -0.173215
6    0.119209
7   -1.044236
8   -0.861849
9         NaN
```

Using shift function values are shifted depending on period given

for example using shift with positive integer shifts rows value downwards:

```
df['value'].shift(1)
```

output

```
0         NaN
1    0.469112
2   -0.282863
3   -1.509059
4   -1.135632
5    1.212112
6   -0.173215
7    0.119209
8   -1.044236
9   -0.861849
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

using shift with negative integer shifts rows value upwards:

```
df['value'].shift(-1)
```

output

```
0   -0.282863
1   -1.509059
2   -1.135632
3    1.212112
4   -0.173215
5    0.119209
6   -1.044236
7   -0.861849
8         NaN
9         NaN
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: can you please explain the freq param to me?

Answer (score 0):

code here wants to put values from the future, make a prediction for 'Adj. Close' Value 
by putting next 10% of data frame-length's value in df['label'] for each row.

```
forecast_out = int(math.ceil(.1*len(df)))
df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)
```

if you print df.tail() you will get NaN value.